How to Use Multiple Types of Questions in Google Forms
I want to add a textQuestion type reponse to have a feed back of the user but I got this error:
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/1LrWf6IHMfww2LH67g32PjDXhx2_Zyi0cfNPI8hDIf8c:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'requests[0].create_item.item.question_item.question' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. 
Cannot set 'textQuestion'". 
Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest',
 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[0].create_item.item.question_item.question', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[0].create_item.item.question_item.question' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'textQuestion'"}]}]">

I used a multiple choice question , and I want to add for the same question a textQuestion, which allow user to give a feed-back
Here is my code :
new_question = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "createItem": {
                "item": {
                    "title": question_text,
                    "questionItem": {
                        "question": {
                            "required": True,
                            "choiceQuestion": {
                                "type": "RADIO",
                                "options": [
                                    {"value": "Oui"},
                                    {"value": "Non"}   
                                ]
                            },
                            "textQuestion": {
                                "paragraph": False
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "index": 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Is there a possibility to add other question types for the same question ?
Or you can only use one type question?

The short answer is, I believe, “no, a question can only contain a single question”. If you want to add a feedback option, add an extra question.
